# Review Security for a product developed on ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, security

We are planning to buy a product that's developed on ASP.NET MVC, JQuery, SQL 2005. .basically latest MS stack. This product is going to store some of very highly sensitive data.

So, we need to evaluate that product in terms of security.

But I'm confused as in How can I certify that this product is secure and we can buy it.

I don't have the luxury to peep into source code unless I buy that product.

What are the options I have?

Comment: How would you evaluate a product based on JavaEE or ASP.NET WebForms or ...?  Get an evaluation copy and beat on it with some security tools.  Require that you or some recognized authority review it for security issues -- perhaps under NDA.  If they won't agree to something that allows you to verify that it's built with the required security in place, don't buy it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not programming related, the only thing you can do is look at any available documentation.  What type of software is it?  Can you call the company and ask for literature?

Comment: Imagine it as something like probably a online banking? I mean as sensitive as it can be..

Comment: You will need to get some sort of eval or free copy to evaluate, you really do not have any other option.  If the company does not want to let you use / eval it then that is a risk you take.
You can also try to consult with past clients.  See how happy they are with the SAME system...